# Disabling auto resolve via address book of Author field in Microsoft Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

Is there a way to disable the Automatic resolution of names entered in the Author section of "Related People" in the Info tab of a Microsoft Word 2010 document?

It appears that after entering the text into the field, Word automatically queries address books it has access to on the current log in and if it finds a single match, applies the coontact card information to the document (email, phone numbers etc)

For example, I have a contact named Christina Doe. If I enter Chris Doe, Word picks this up as a match for the existing contact Christina Doe.